# Jackson fails to recognize @class type identifier in JSON payload

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

I have an hierarchy of Java POJOS, the base class being abstract. To ensure Jackson can deserialize from JSON into the correct concrete types I have annotated the base class with `@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)`. However, I receive the following error when Jackson attemps deserialization:

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.foo.MyAbstractClass]: missing type id property '@class'
 at [Source: (byte[])""{\"id\":10,\"params\":[\"foo\",\"bar\"],\"@class\":\"com.foo.MyConcreteClass\"}""; line: 1, column: 1]
```

The type identifier field `@class` is in the JSON payload but Jackson fails to find it. Any idea what's going on? Note that the Jackson deserialization is happening transparently; I am using Spring Cloud Stream.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. Turns out the message payload was actually being interpreted by Jackson as a JSON String value and not a JSON object, due to how it was being sent by the producer application. By stripping the outer quotes and unescaping it Jackson was then parsing the string correctly.